# mobile nav bar absent - github pages iridium template

Tags: javascript, css, html, mobile, github-pages

I'm using a creative commons [template](http://templated.co/iridium) for my github pages. However, while the mobile version of the template shows the navigation in the upper left hand corner, the mobile version of my [github page](http://brandonlind.github.io) does not. Any suggestions? Code for my version is on my [github](http://github.com/brandonlind/brandonlind.github.io). This began as soon as I committed the template to my pages, and an unaltered template on my github pages is viewable [here](https://brandonlind.github.io/templated-iridium/index.html) (to show absence of nav).

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally I thought that the problem had to do with the order of your script tags but upon looking at the console you seem to be getting some errors (`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://brandonlind.github.io/' was loaded over HTTPS`).  I would try adding an "s" to your script links ala `http:// to https://`.

Try changing:

```
<script>"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

to:

```
<script>"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

I'm not 100% sure this will solve the problem, but I think it might help.
If it can't properly read the jquery script tag then it would be able to read the other script tags.

Comment: I applied the suggested edits, and committed to github (now live).

The mobile nav bar still isn't there. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Hmm... I updated my answer.  Hopefully it is a better solution : )

Comment: that did it. Thanks!